# Receiving real/user/system times within main logic of C++

Tags: c++

Is there a UNIX time equivalent in C++, which gives real, user and system time of execution preferably within main? Or are there non-trivial ways to use chrono, etc to achieve the same functionality?

Could not find chrono usage to `record all three timestamps`, but `only the real time based on timeclock` [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock).

Aiming to walk away from redirection operator coupled with executable and trying to embed time logic within main itself.
`time a.out 2> log.txt`

Comment: Please show us some code to illustrate. Btw; what's wrong with `std::chrono`?

Comment: Not in Standard C++. C++ is a big tent and not all systems make time available in this manner. There might be a Unix C call that provides this, but my usefulness to you ends at this point.

Comment: Quick google  finds: https://linux.die.net/man/2/times

Comment: @JesperJuhl give the question a re-read, my question was different and there is a snippet on redirection operator which I attempt to walk away from.

Comment: It's customary to not add any kind of "solved" marks to the title. Instead you should *accept* your answer when you'll be able to (after the timeout).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved using `sys/times.h` and `clock_t`.

For both methods, system time `sys` was recorded using times.h, and clock_t's REALTIME was more accurate for `user` recording.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/times.h>

std::string parse_tim(intmax_t milliseconds) {
  std::string parsed;

  intmax_t s = milliseconds / 1000;
  intmax_t m = s / 60;
  intmax_t h = m / 60;
  intmax_t d = h / 24;

  if(d > 0)
    parsed = parsed + std::to_string(d) + "d";
  if(! parsed.empty() || h > 0)
    parsed = parsed + std::to_string(h%24) + "h";
  if(! parsed.empty() || m > 0)
    parsed = parsed + std::to_string(m%60) + "m";

  parsed = parsed + std::to_string(s%60) + ".";
  parsed = parsed + std::to_string(milliseconds%1000) + "s";

  return parsed;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  static struct tms st_cpu, en_cpu;
  struct timespec ts1, tw1, ts2, tw2;

  static clock_t st_time = times(&st_cpu);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &ts1);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tw1);


  // Perform operations
  // Perform operation
  // Perform actions


  static clock_t en_time = times(&en_cpu);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tw2);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &ts2);

  auto real_clock = (intmax_t)(en_time - st_time) * 10;
  auto user_clock = (intmax_t)(en_cpu.tms_utime - st_cpu.tms_utime) * 10;
  auto sys_clock = (intmax_t)(en_cpu.tms_stime - st_cpu.tms_stime) * 10;
  std::cerr << "time.h\treal\t" << parse_tim(real_clock) << "\t"
            << "user\t" << parse_tim(user_clock) << "\t"
            << "sys\t" << parse_tim(sys_clock) << std::endl;

  auto real_dur = intmax_t(1000.0*tw2.tv_sec + 1e-6*tw2.tv_nsec - (1000.0*tw1.tv_sec + 1e-6*tw1.tv_nsec));
  auto user_dur = intmax_t(1000.0*ts2.tv_sec + 1e-6*ts2.tv_nsec - (1000.0*ts1.tv_sec + 1e-6*ts1.tv_nsec));
  auto sys_dur = intmax_t(en_cpu.tms_stime - st_cpu.tms_stime) * 10;
  std::cerr << "clock_t\treal\t" << parse_tim(real_dur) << "\t"
            << "user\t" << parse_tim(user_dur) << "\t"
            << "sys\t" << parse_tim(sys_dur) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

`time ./a.out`

```
time.h    real  4m2.460s    user    5m57.140s   sys 21.830s
clock_t   real  4m2.457s    user    6m18.976s   sys 21.830s

real    4m2.498s
user    6m22.816s
sys     0m26.865s
```